# not able to get the table row value with specific class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a below table code. I would like to get the table row value  which has class as"highlight", below is the code which i tried but i am getting null. Please someone help.

table name = itemtable; table rows will be loaded dynamically using jquery.

```html
<table cellspacing="0"  cellpadding="0" id="itemtable" class="t1" border="1px"> 
    <thead>
    <tr>
     <th> SLno</th>
        <th>Item code</th> 
        <th>Item name</th> 
        <th>Received qty</th>  
  <th>Insp Date</th> 
        <th>Accepted qty</th>   
        <th>Rejected qty</th>      
        <th>Remarks</th>          
    </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

using below code to highlight the row using class ".highlight" when user db click on itemtable row.

```js
$(document).on("dblclick", "#itemtable tr", function (e) {
 //high light the table row
 $('#itemtable tr').not(this).removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight'); 
});
```

now i am  trying to get one of the  value say first , which has class as highlight( ie row which is selected) in another flow of program (after highlight).

```js
var selectedrow = $('#itemtable tr.highlight');
    var slno = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(2)').text();
```

Comment: Which element does `this` refers? Show the complete code

Comment: There is no element with class `highlight`

Comment: Please provide more code as context, for example what is `this` and where is the `tr` with the class `highlight`?

Comment: There is no element classed `.highlight` and in your code `this` is just going to refer to the `window` object-- did you accidentally omit some code?

Comment: @anied. table row will be loaded dynamically. and also whenever user db click on table row, class will be changed to highlight. Please check my edited code

Comment: @kavi -- whatever code is driving the behavior you are describing will be crucial to answering this question.  Please provide it in the snippet, as well as provide a clear description of what is expected and what is wrong.  This will assist the community in providing you an answer quickly and completely.

Comment: Your edits are not a working single snippet, so it is still difficult to say.  If we presume that the markup you are adding dynamically is properly formed and contains `td` elements that contain text, and we presume that your highlighting code is working correctly, and knowing nothing about the context in which your final snippet is being called, then @court3nay 's answer should be correct.  There is something else going on but with what you have provided it will not really be possible to tell what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
var selectedRow = $('#itemtable tr.highlight');
var slno = selectedRow.find('td:eq(2)').text();
```

Comment: Thanks! but no luck:(

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working.

```js
var selectedrow = $('.highlight');
    var slno = selectedrow.closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the ajax response. It would be better if you had share the ajax code. Though try with below code:

```
<table id="itemtable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SLno</th>
            <th>Item code</th> 
            <th>Item name</th> 
            <th>Received qty</th>  
            <th>Insp Date</th> 
            <th>Accepted qty</th>   
            <th>Rejected qty</th>      
            <th>Remarks</th>          
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        ...Your ajax response will append here...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('table#itemtable').find('tr.highlight').each(function(i, v){
            $(v).find('td').each(function(v1){
                console.log($(this).text());
            });
        });
    }, 4000);
});
```

Let me know if it works for you. I have added a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/singhaloke/kw7mvj3a/9/).